# Issue finding a file in a list to be rewritten

Tags: python, python-2.7, nested-lists, file-writing

Very new to Python and programming in general so apologies if I am missing anything straightforward.

I am trying to iterate through a directory and open the included .txt files and modify them with new content.

```
 import os

 def rootdir(x):
     for paths, dirs, files in os.walk(x):
         for filename in files:
             f=open(filename, 'r')
             lines=f.read()
             f.close()
             for line in lines:
                 f=open(filename, 'w')
                 newline='rewritten content here'
                 f.write(newline)
                 f.close()
 return x

 rootdir("/Users/russellculver/documents/testfolder")`
```

Is giving me: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'TestText1.rtf'

**EDIT: I should clarify there IS a file named 'TestText1.rtf' in the folder specified in the function argument. It is the first one of three text files.**

When I try moving where the file is closed / opened as seen below:

```
import os

 def rootdir(x):
     for paths, dirs, files in os.walk(x):
         for filename in files:
             f=open(filename, 'r+')
             lines=f.read()
             for line in lines:
                  newline='rewritten content here'
                  f.write(newline)
                  f.close()
 return x

 rootdir("/Users/russellculver/documents/testfolder")
```

It gives me: ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Thanks for any thoughts in advance.

@mescalinum Okay so I've made amendments to what I've got based on everyones assistance (thanks!), but it is still failing to enter the text "newline" in any of the .txt files in the specified folder.

```
import os

x = raw_input("Enter the directory here: ")

def rootdir(x):
    for dirpaths, dirnames, files in os.walk(x):
        for filename in files:
            try:
                with open(os.dirpaths.join(filename, 'w')) as f:
                    f.write("newline")
                return x
            except:
                print "There are no files in the directory or the files cannot be opened!"
            return x
```

Comment: Your `f.close()` is in a wrong place.

Comment: Hey  - thanks, for which option? The first or second? Is it indented wrong? Or just plain placed at the wrong point?

Comment: I am working on it. Just a moment.

Comment: shouldn't be `f=open(os.path.join(paths, filename), 'r')`?

Comment: @RishavKundu added modified code.

Comment: @mescalinum added modified code.

Comment: `with open(os.dirpaths.join(filename, 'w')) as f:`??? try `with open(os.path.join(dirpaths, filename), 'w') as f:`

Comment: @mescalinum I've got it executing now, however it keeps throwing my exception, meaning it's not able to open and write the file for some reason.

    import os

`x = raw_input("Enter the directory path here: ")

def rootdir(x):
    for dirpaths, dirnames, files in os.walk(x):
        for filename in files:
            try:
                with open(os.paths.join(dirpaths, filename), 'a') as f:
                    f.write("newline")
            except:
                print "Directory empty or unable to open file."
            return x
rootdir(x)`

returns Directory empty or unable to open file

Answer (score 2):

From https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk:

> **os.walk(top, topdown=True, onerror=None, followlinks=False)**
>
> Generate the file names in a directory tree by walking the tree either top-down or bottom-up. For each directory in the tree rooted at directory top (including top itself), it yields a 3-tuple `(dirpath, dirnames, filenames)`.
>
> `dirpath` is a string, the path to the directory. `dirnames` is a list of the names of the subdirectories in `dirpath` (excluding `'.'` and `'..'`). `filenames` is a list of the names of the non-directory files in `dirpath`. Note that the names in the lists contain no path components. **To get a full path (which begins with top) to a file or directory in `dirpath`, do `os.path.join(dirpath, name)`.**

---

Also, `f.close()` should be outside `for line in lines`, otherwise you call it multiple times, and the second time you call it, `f` is already closed, and it will give that I/O error.

---

You should avoid explicitly `open()`ing and `close()`ing files, like:

```
f=open(filename, 'w')
f.write(newline)
f.close()
```

and instead use [context managers](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) (i.e. the `with` statement):

```
with open(filename, 'w'):
    f.write(newline)
```

which does exactly the same thing, but implicitly closes the file when the body of `with` is finished.

Comment: Hey, I just wanted to ask if a direct `paths+filename` has any problem?

Comment: Additionally, I would suggest having a look at [`with open(filename) as f`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects)

Comment: @RishavKundu: e.g. `dirpath` is something like `'/a/b/c'`, and `filename` is `'f'`, with `dirpath+filename` you get `'/a/b/cf'`

Answer (score -2):

Here is the code that does as you asked:

```
import os

def rootdir(x):
     for paths, dirs, files in os.walk(x):
         for filename in files:
             try:
                 f=open(os.path.join(dirpath, name), 'w')
                 f.write('new content here')
                 f.close()
             except Exception, e:
                print "Could not open " + filename

rootdir("/Users/xrisk/Desktop")
```

However, I have a feeling you don’t *quite* understand what’s happening here (no offence). First have a look at the documentation of `os.walk` provided by @mescalinum . The third tuple element `files` will contain only the file name. You need to combine it with `paths` to get a full path to the file.

Also, you don’t need to read the file first to write to it. On the other hand, if you want to *append* to the file, you should use the mode 'a' when opening the file

In general, when reading/writing a file, you only close it **after** finishing all the read/writes. Otherwise you will get an exception.

Thanks @mescalinum